# DROPDOWN ID not being passed in CONTROLLER using ONCHANGE event AJAX

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

My scenario is this.
I have two dropdown options: Building and Floor. What I want is, when I change/click the value of the dropdown "Building", it fills up how many floor it is. So for example, the dropdown "building" has two options, let say, building1 which has 10 floors and building2 which has 5 floors. So when I select, building1, it will give 10 options in the dropdown "Floor". And when I change it to building2, it will fill up again the dropdown "floor" with only 5 options representing the No.of floors for that building.

[image]

So here is my codes:
**VIEW:**

```
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                &times;
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="H3">Add New Room</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <label>Building</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="rt" id="bldg" onchange="activate_floor();">
                                        <option>Select Bldg. No</option>
                                        <?php
                                        if ($bldg_list) {
                                            foreach ($bldg_list as $row) {
                                                echo "<option value=\"" . $row -> buid . "\">" . $row -> budesc . "</option>";
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>



                                    <label>Floor</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="flr" id="flr">
                                        <option>Select Floor. No</option>
                                        <?php
                                        if ($flr_list) {
                                            $str = 1;
                                            foreach ($flr_list as $row) {
                                                while($str <= $row -> flr ){                                                        
                                                  echo "<option value=\"" . $str . "\">" . $str . "</option>";  
                                                  $str++;
                                                } 
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>



                                    <label>Room</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Room No." required="required" id="rno" name="rno" />

                                    <label>Room Type</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="rt" id="rt">
                                        <option>Select Room Type</option>
                                        <?php
                                        if ($roomtype_list) {
                                            foreach ($roomtype_list as $row) {
                                                echo "<option value=\"" . $row -> rtcode . "\">" . $row -> rtdesc . "</option>";
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                Close
                            </button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Save
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--END MODAL WINDOW -->
```

As you can see, I assigned a function ACTIVATE_FLOOR() on the event ONCHANGE for the dropdown BUILDING.

And here is the AJAX part which I positioned at the footer.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('select#flr').attr('disabled',true);
}); 


function activate_floor(){
    var bldg_id = $('select#bldg').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url('csettings/display_room/' )?>',
        data: 'buid='+bldg_id,
        success: function() {
            $('select#flr').attr('disabled',false);
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}   
</script>
```

This is my **CONTROLLER**:

```
public function display_room(){
   $buid = $this -> security -> xss_clean($this -> input -> post('buid'));
   $data['room_list']       = $this -> msettings -> get_room();
   $data['roomtype_list']   = $this -> msettings -> get_roomtype();
   $data['bldg_list']       = $this -> msettings -> get_bldg();     
   $data['flr_list']        = $this -> msettings -> get_flr($buid);
   $this -> display_view('vroom',$data);
}
```

When I debug using Chromes Developer Tool, I found out that the ID of the dropdown "Building" is correctly being passed in the URL as seen below. 
[image]

But my issue now is, this value is not being retrieved in my CONTROLLER.

Comment: so what part of the controller is the most relevant? can you think of any `console.log` messages that might help debug?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your reply.Please take a look at this screenshot which I take in the console logs. As I noticed, the request query string dont add the ID of the dropdown although the response gives status 200.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in controller

> $this->input->get_post('buid')

instead of

> $this->input->post('buid')

It seems that the parameter is being passed as a query string.